# PHP ldap_bind() local issues

Tags: php, ldap

I've a script which need to display an user list on my company's Active Directory.

To perform It, I'm using a dedicated AD account (which is authorized to search on the AD). I'm doing It this way:

```
$ldapResource = ldap_connect('ldap://*********');
ldap_set_option($ldapResource, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapResource, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

ldap_bind($ldapResource, "CN=My company standard Account, OU=*******", "account_password");
```

Then, i'm doing the search

```
ldap_search(...)
```

By doing this, the problem is that when I run the script locally (with xampp), I lose my current account privileges (like Internet access, because the standard account doesn't have this right ?).

If I want to be logged back as my real profile, I need to run a script that authenticate me (ldap_bind()) with my own credentials.

Is there any solution to avoid losing my main authentication ? Should I perform the research in another way ?

Comment: What OS are you working on? Is that on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try example below to see if it works. It lists all users. Change the variables as it fits you. Check [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ajgd/writin-ldap-applications-with-php) for more examples.

```
$username = 'yowyow';
$password = '123123';
$server = '192.168.32.4';
$domain = '@yourdomain.local';
$port = 389;

$connection = ldap_connect($server, $port);
if (!$connection) {
    exit('Connection failed');
}

// Help talking to AD
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($connection, $username.$domain, $password);
if (!$bind) {
    exit('Binding failed');
}

// This is where you can do your work
$unit = 'sales';
$distinguished_name = "OU=$unit,DC=yourdomain,DC=local";
$filter = "(sAMAccountName=*)";

$search = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $distinguished_name, $filter);
$total_record = ldap_count_entries($ldap_connection, $search);
$returned = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $search);

if ($total_record > 0) {
    print_r($returned);
}
// End

ldap_close($ldap_connection);
```

Comment: actually the search is not the problem, my script works fine for listing users. The real problem is that I lose my windows authentication when the script is runned on localhost (after the ldap_bind(), for example I lose my Internet access because the used account doesn't have this privilege)